# Can file log deletion raise any problem?

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms

Is it safe to delete log file, because I have a big size log file ?

Another question: can I restore a transaction log backup to another server ? I just 
want ensure about that.

Comment: How are you proposing to delete the log file? If you just shut down SQL Server and delete it then it could definitely cause you problems as it could contain details of active transactions that would be processed during restart recovery. What recovery model is your database in? What backup needs do you have?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe to delete transaction log.  But you can shrink it:

2005

```
backup log XXX with truncate_only .... 
dbcc shrinkfile
```

2008

```
Alter database xxx set recovery simple
dbcc shrinkfile
Alter database xxx set recovery full
```

> can I restore a transaction log backup to another server

Yes, you can, but before you need to restore LAST FULL backup to another server.